# is "SELECT fieldname, fieldName FROM MY_TABLE;" ever valid for any SQL database?

Tags: sql

Do any SQL databases have case-sensitive naming for field names?

What I mean is, in Java you can have two variables ...

```
String fieldname = "a";
String fieldName = "b";
```

Are there any SQL databases support that so ...

```
SELECT fieldname, fieldName FROM MY_TABLE;
```

... would return two different columns?

I'm asking because I'm building a database utility that has to work for MySQL, H2, PostgreSQL, Oracle, and SQL Server, so I need to know how they all work for a bit of code I'm writing.

Comment: Tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: @AvaTaylor . . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the SQL standard, SQL identifiers are case-insensitive.  So, without escape characters, these refer to the same column:

```
select fieldname, fieldName
```

However, you can *escape* the names and they become distinguishable.  The standard SQL escape character is `"`:

```
select "fieldname", "fieldName"
```

But some databases don't support this and have their own.

Answer (score 3):

In most databases (and in all those you tagged), an unquoted identifier is case-insensitive. Meaning that `fieldname` and `fieldName` are the same thing: the database folds them into the default case, which makes them equivalent.

In most databases, you can make an identifier case-sensitive by *quoting* it. The quoting character varies across databases. In standard SQL, you use double quotes. So `"fieldname"` and `"fieldName"` are two different things. Oracle and Postgres follow that standard. SQL Server wants square brackets (`[]`); MySQL wants backticks.

In a nutshell: in SQL, I would not recommend using case-sensitive identifiers. This makes things more complicated for no value added. In my opinion, snake case style is your best pick in SQL, because upper/lower case are meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, you can certainly have case-sensitive column names, they just need to be quoted.  So this query would return data from three separate columns

```
SELECT "columnName", "ColumnName", columnName
  FROM table
```

In SQL Server, you can have case-sensitive columns but they need to be enclosed in brackets, i.e.

```
SELECT [ColumnName], [columnName], [columnname]
  FROM table
```